# Проблема с отсчетом setInterval в Javascript

Tags: javascript, setinterval

у меня такой вопрос: почему, для того, чтобы отсчет шел до 0, нужно i = -2(Естественно когда i = 0, отсчет идет до 2).
Вот код:

```js
let output = document.getElementById('output');
let i = 9;
let id;

id = setInterval(function() {
  output.innerHTML = i;
  i--;
  if (i == -2) {
    output.innerHTML = 'Отсчёт завершен.';
    clearInterval(id);
  }
}, 300);
```

```html
<div id='output'>10</div>
```

Заранее спасибо, и извините, если здесь этот вопрос оказался глупым, новичок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что, если Вы хотите видеть `"0"` в течение интервала таймера (как все остальные числа), то Вам нужно, чтобы таймер сработал еще раз со значением `i` на входе в него `-1`. В этот момент `output.innerHTML` становится `"-1"`, но еще не успевает отрисоваться. Потом `i` уменьшается еще на единицу `i--;`и становится `-2`. A `output.innerHTML` меняется на `"Отсчёт завершен."`.

Answer (score 0):

Измени логику, будет легче понять код:

```
id = setInterval(function() {
  output.innerHTML = i;
  if (i < 0) {
    output.innerHTML = 'Отсчёт завершен.';
    clearInterval(id);
  }
  i--;
}, 300);
```